# How can I forcibly change a shared library version used by my code from a certain folder than the default one in /usr/local/lib/?

Tags: make, shared-libraries

I have an app I am building on Linux (Ubuntu). The steps involved are `./configure` with certain options, `make`, and then execute the app.

By default the app links/uses a shared library present in the folder /usr/local/lib/libstarpu.so.0, but I have downloaded the latest source for this Starpu and installed it in my home $HOME/lib/.

I tried using this new library as an input to the configure command as below and even removed the /usr/local/lib from my LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but still when I check with ldd, it seems to show the executable is built with the old version of the library in /usr/local/lib.

```
./configure LDFLAGS="-l:$HOME/lib/libstarpu.so.0"
```

How do I make my build system to use the newer version of this shared library in a different folder than the system default of /usr/local/lib?

Do I need to modify anything in my build related makefiles, configure files?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/lib" ./configure
```

Anyway, check the environment variables explained here:

```
man ld.so
```